# SSH rules are not being honoured

Tags: ssh, alma-linux

For some reason, restrictions are no longer being applied for SSH. I can login as any users and choose any authentication method. I have created a test user and test user is not in the allow list but can still login login as any users and with any authentication method.

Rules were enforced before but now have stopped. It's happening on an AlmaLinux 8 system.

Here's what is in place:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no

Match User nagios
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User meta
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User yubi Address 10.10.0.201/32
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    AllowUsers yubi

Match Address 10.10.0.0/24
        AllowUsers meta

Match Address 22.22.22.22
        AllowUsers nagios
```

Problem is occurring on AlmaLinux 9 also. It seems user override no longer works. Here's the complete entry in my AlmaLinux 9 file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sshd_custom_rules.conf`

```
## Custom SSH rules
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication no

Match Address 192.168.68.0/22
    AllowUsers yubi repository-admin

Match User yubi
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication no

Match User repository-admin
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

The main `sshd_config` is set to the default. The uncommented lines are as below.

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port 22
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Here's the content in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-redhat.conf`

```
# This system is following system-wide crypto policy. The changes to
# crypto properties (Ciphers, MACs, ...) will not have any effect in
# this or following included files. To override some configuration option,
# write it before this block or include it before this file.
# Please, see manual pages for update-crypto-policies(8) and sshd_config(5).
Include /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

# It is recommended to use pam_motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of PrintMotd,
# as it is more configurable and versatile than the built-in version.
PrintMotd no
```

If I remove the user from the config file, they are unable to login. Once enabled, the user is able to access with all authentication method despite only granting them `PubkeyAuthentication` or `PasswordAuthentication`.

Comment: Your configuration does not seem to stop a user called `test` from connecting if they connect from an IP address that isn't matched with a `Match Address` rule.  What IP address are they connecting from?

Comment: Same as nagios which is rather odd since user is not even there. I tried looking around for an AllowUsers outside of the block but none found.

Comment: ....implying that you've not provided the whole sshd_config here.

Comment: There's not much else in the ```sshd_config```. I have added the lines that are not commented.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable password authentication, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` needs to be set as `no`.

Comment: Note that the option you mention is deprecated and that you should use `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` instead.

Comment: I've updated it to `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` and it is working also